# How do I keep awk variables in scope?

Tags: awk

I am attempting to keep track of the lowest/highest values from a list of counties and populations.  I can't figure out how to stop variables from resetting themselves at 0.

This is my cmd.awk file.

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"
    HPD=0
    HPDname=""
    LPD=0
    LPDname=""
    HPW=0
    HPWname=""
    LPW=0
    LPWname=""
}
# Stuff in here needs to be printed during the process.
{
  print $1
  PD=$2/$4
  print PD
  PW=($3/($3+$4))*100
  print PW

# These if statements see if there is a new highest or lowest value for the     categories.
  if ($PD>$HPD)
  {
    HPD=$PD
    HPDname=$1
  }
  if ($PD<$LPD)
  {
    LPD=$PD
    LPDname=$1
  }
  if ($PW>$HPW)
  {
    HPW=$PW
    HPWname=$1
  }
  if ($PW<$LPW)
  {
    LPW=$PW
    LPWname=$1
  }
}

# Prints off all of the ending information that we have been keeping track      of.
END {
    print "The highest population density: "$HPDname" "$HPD
    print "The lowest population density: "$LPDname" "$LPD
    print "The highest percentage of water: "$HPWname" "$HPW
    print "The lowest percentage of water: "$LPWname" "$LPW
}
```

The output of END always shows the last county to be analyzed instead of keeping track of the highest or lowest.

Comment: Awk variables aren't dereferenced with `$`.

Comment: What Michael Homer said. So if `PD` currently equals 2 then `$PD` is a reference to field 2, just like `$2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify what the commenters noted in code:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"
    HPD=0
    HPDname=""
    LPD=0
    LPDname=""
    HPW=0
    HPWname=""
    LPW=0
    LPWname=""
}
# Stuff in here needs to be printed during the process.
{
  print $1
  PD=$2/$4
  print PD
  PW=($3/($3+$4))*100
  print PW

# These if statements see if there is a new highest or lowest value for the     categories.
  if (PD>HPD)
  {
    HPD=PD
    HPDname=$1
  }
  if (PD<LPD)
  {
    LPD=PD
    LPDname=$1
  }
  if (PW>HPW)
  {
    HPW=PW
    HPWname=$1
  }
  if (PW<LPW)
  {
    LPW=PW
    LPWname=$1
  }
}

# Prints off all of the ending information that we have been keeping track      of.
END {
    print "The highest population density: "HPDname" "HPD
    print "The lowest population density: "LPDname" "LPD
    print "The highest percentage of water: "HPWname" "HPW
    print "The lowest percentage of water: "LPWname" "LPW
}
```

You're mixing up Bash like variable syntax and awk.

Bash:

```
variable='something'
echo $something
```

awk:

```
variable="something"
print variable
```

awk uses $ for the field variables, like $1, $2, $0, $NF, but NOT for variables you have created. I think that's more or less right technically though I have to admit I never read up on the specifics.

[variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Ops.html#Assignment-Ops)